# do loop for structure check already exist or not

Tags: xml, vb.net, loops

My program contains:

- "TEXTBOX1" as ID
- "ADD" button to save all the data in structure everytime I click it
- "SAVE" button to save all the items the structure into xml file

To save all the data after clicking the ADD button already succeeds.

The thing is I want to compare if the data/element key in already exist or not.

If the data/element already exist then `msgbox("ID ALREADY EXIST")`
If not proceed to add

So I started coding with this code, the problem is, its only compares the first element but not others. Please  help.

```
Public Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim index As Integer = Nothing
    If ioDevice IsNot Nothing Then
        index = ioDevice.Length
    Else
        index = 0
    End If
    ReDim Preserve ioDevice(index)

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    With ioDevice(index)
        Do
            If ioDevice IsNot Nothing AndAlso ioDevice(i).DeviceID = TextBox1.Text = False Then
                MsgBox("PROCEED")
                .DeviceID = device.DeviceID
                .ConfigFile = device.ConfigFile
                .Dll = device.Dll
            Else
                MsgBox("ALREADY EXIST")
                device.DeviceID = vbEmpty
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop Until i < ioDevice.Length + 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Some of your question have answers but you didn't post any feedback (including a comment or accepting the answer. If the answer doesn't work or you have any question about the answer post a feedback to the author of answer. Also if the answer solved your problem, accept it by click on check-mark near the answer. Take a look at [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should change.

Instead of using an array for `ioDevice`, use a `List(Of ...)`. This is way easier to manage and it avoids the `ReDim Preserve`, which is very inefficient.

Secondly, it is probably reasonable to define a constructor for the device type that takes the required arguments. This way, you can be sure that all required fields are set when you use it. It seems that your device type is a structure. Unless you have specific reasons for that, I would suggest to make it a class.

The check for existence should be separated from the actual action. In fact, if you need to access the devices by ID, a different data structure like a `Dictionary(Of ..., ...)` would be more appropriate. But for now, let's stick to the list.

And rename your controls to match their purpose `Button2` and `TextBox1` are not expressive at all.

So in the end, your code would look like this:

```vb
Public Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim newDeviceId = TextBox1.Text
    'Check if it already exists
    Dim exists = False
    For Each device in ioDevice 'Remember that ioDevice is now a list
        If device.DeviceID = newDeviceId Then
            exists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If exists Then
        MsgBox("ALREADY EXIST")
    Else
        MsgBox("PROCEED")
        ioDevice.Add(New Device(newDeviceId, ...)) 'Any other parameter you defined in the constructor
    End If
End Sub
```

Actually, the existence check could be done more neatly with lambda expressions:

```vb
Dim exists = ioDevice.Any(Function (device) device.DeviceID = newDeviceId)
```

This will check the entire list if there is any device with the new id. And you could remove the subsequent `For Each` loop.